# Is Dharma of all people different ? How to know one's own dharma with precison?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, dharma

Perhaps dharma of all people are different . It is indicated in this verse of Gita -

> BG 18.47 — Faulty Swa-Dharma  is better than well performed Para-Dharma ; Naturally prescribed performance of Karma never achieves sinful reactions.

How to know which one is my Dharma with precision ?

Is one's dharma only dependent upon the caste in which he is born ? Or there are some other factors also which need to be considered as what is one's dharma ?

Comment: varnashrama dharma is basis of all. varna = 4 (brahman, kshatriya, vaishya, shudra). ashram = 4 (brahmacharya, gruhastha, vanaprastha, sanyasa). every person will belong to one of the 4x4 combinations, IF they are Hindu, or they will be mixed, in which case certain occupations are prescribed for them. or they will be avarna/mleccha like foreigners